# broadcast receiver does not work after killing my app

Tags: java

```java
{
  public void CustomNotification() {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_reminder_notification);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("notification", "reminder");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    createNotificationChannel();
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
       .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_pzizz)
       .setTicker(context.getString(R.string.about))
       .setTimeoutAfter(3000)
       .setContentIntent(pIntent)
       .setContent(remoteViews)
       .setAutoCancel(true);

   remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txtTitle, sharedPreferencesHelper.getReminderNotificationName());
   NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());
 }

 private void createNotificationChannel() {
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") 
      NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
          CHANNEL_ID,
          context.getString(R.string.app_name),
          NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
      );
      serviceChannel.setSound(null, null);
      manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain your question in more detail? Also, please edit your code, because it isn't all formatted.

Comment: I fixed your code formatting, but you need to edit your question to explain what the expected behaviour is, and how your example is not working (i.e., error message, what incorrect behaviour, etc.). Otherwise you are likely to get effective help.

Comment: Not completely sure, but I guess, this is intended behaviour. If a user kills an App, it should not restart automatically without a user action.

Comment: i set permission for alarm manager in manifest file  RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED and SET_ALARM but still alarm doesn't working